# NAT client having troube print to Windows 2003 print server on public domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, nat, print-server

We have a NATed wireless network and a printer server with Public IP that can be resolved with FQDN. We are having trouble printing from the NATed (private) netwrok to the print server on the public network.

We found this article and it make total sense.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2444558

it basicly stated that when you are access the computer via SMB. If the connection is coming from the same IP teh latter connection will disconnect the previous connection. Since it is coming from a NATed netwrok it will look like it is coming from teh same IP, therefore the connection will get disconnected.

The trouble is the article is for Windows 2008 and our print server is windows 2003.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You have four options:

1. Don't NAT your wireless network.
2. Multihome your print server with an interface on the wireless network.
3. Put a dedicated print server on the wireless network.
4. Use [Internet printing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731368(v=ws.10).aspx) instead of SMB.

Comment: @ MDMarra. Thank you very much for you suggestion. We are going to try the oPtion 2, 3 just wanted to see what other options are out there. as for Option 4. we have to check if Pcounter software works with that. We will let you know how it works out.

Comment: Oh, PCounter? I know your pain.

Comment: Just circling back and put in some update so that people having the same issue can have some reference. We end up adding a new NIC to the print server and give it an IP that is on teh Netted network. Register the "printers" on the WINS server that serves the wirelss work to with the Netted address. Bunch of patch work, not optimal but works. @MDMarra thansk for the help.